# List.Orderby in C# first aplabetical on one value then by lowest to highest on another value

Tags: c#, list, sorting, compare, jquery-ui-sortable

So I have a List of values lets call the list:

```
private List<Deliverable> myDeliverables;
```

`myDeliverables` contains another object called `Buyer`. Buyer has a `string Street` and a `int housenumber`.

Now I want to sort first by streetaddress then by housenumber so I get

```
AAstreet 10
AAstreet 12
BAstreet 5
BBstreet 5
BBstreet 6
(...)
```

I did this `myDeliverables = myDeliverables.OrderBy(x => x.Buyer.Street).ToList();` this sort by address, but not sure how to add a second value in the orderby method.. I am also very unsure how this OrderBy works in the first place. The VS documentation is a little difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

```
var result = myDeliverables.
OrderBy(x => x.Buyer.Street).
ThenBy( x => x.Buyer.HouseNum).ToList();
```

Comment: Here is the link where you should get all possibilities.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort by additional value then you need to use `ThenBy`:

```
myDeliverables = myDeliverables.
                   OrderBy(x => x.Buyer.Street).
                   ThenBy(x => x.Buyer.HouseNumber).
                   ToList();
```